# ROLLBACK Rendered > Why is it rolling back in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

For some reason when I try sending an email through the contact form I get an error as shown below. I don't know why this is happening, it happens only on heroku but not on local host. What could be the issue?

**Error:**

```
Processing by FeedbacksController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"feedback"=>{"first_name"=>"Antony", "last_name"=>"Pane", "email"=>"anthony@gmail.com", "message"=>"Testing"}, "commit"=>"Submit Message"}
(0.7ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "feedbacks" ("created_at", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "message", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sun, 20 Dec 2015 12:23:56 PST -08:00], ["email", "anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com"], ["first_name", "Antony"], ["last_name", "Pane"], ["message", "Testing"], ["updated_at", Sun, 20 Dec 2015 12:23:56 PST -08:00]]
(0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered errors/error_500.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 118ms (Views: 4.9ms | ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)
```

**feedback.rb**

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :last_name, presence: { message: "Last name can't be blank" }
  validates :first_name, presence: { message: "First name can't be blank" }
  validates :email, presence: { message: "Email can't be blank" }
  validates :message, presence: { message: "Message can't be blank" }

  validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, on: :create, message: "Email is not valid" }

  after_create :notify_by_mail

  def notify_by_mail
    AppMailer.feedback_notification(self).deliver!
  end
end
```

Please advise!

**Update**

```
def create
  @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @feedback.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Message was delivered.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @feedback}
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @feedback.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the database and forgot to migrate your production?

Comment: Can you include the code you have in `FeedbacksController`?

Comment: @SeanMarzug-McCarthy updated!